# Qt designer Python Tableview Item

Tags: python, qt

I am using Qt to create a GUI with a TableWidget. But there is something that i don't understand. When I write something in the Table, and I try to get it in a variable, it put this in the variable : 
`<PyQt5.QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem object at 0x00000000033B3D38>`
How can I get the value of the content of a cell ?

my code :
`data=self.tableWidget.item (0, 0)
print(data)`
what I get with the print is what I wrote below.

Regards.
Ka

Comment: If it can help someone i found this website which explains how to use classes of Qt : http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html

Comment: Please do not change the question itself to indicate that it is resolved. When you can, upvote and accept an answer that has fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code data has type `QTableWidgetItem`. To read data from this item use `data(int role)` function, that returns QVariant. Then you can get value from `QVariant var` like `var.toInt()` or `var.toString()` etc. For your code:

```
data=self.tableWidget.item (0, 0).data(0).toString()
```

QTableWidgetItem can contain several values with different roles. 0 - DisplayRole (string that you see in widget). You can read more about it in official documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qtablewidgetitem.html